# Where do I find Firestore index error details?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm getting this error in the console when running my application in production:

> {"code":"failed-precondition","name":"FirebaseError"}

I'm assuming this is a firestore index or rules error, but there are no details around which query is causing the problem. Firebase used to put a URL in the console to build missing indexes, but that feature seems to be gone.

Everything works as expected with no errors when running on an emulator.

Comment: "Firebase used to put a URL in the console to build missing indexes, but that feature seems to be gone." I don't think anything changed there. Are you sure you're logging errors and warnings in production/release builds of your app?

Comment: Yeah. They seemed to disappear when I switch to the new modular js libraries. I am getting errors, but only that one I mentioned in the post with no additional information or anything useful in the stack trace.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible code and your package.json which contains the version of Firebase that you're using.